# html5 object autoplay stop not working

Tags: jquery, html, object

Below is my object tag

When its load then `object` tag have `video tag inside` and its play so how can i stop autoplay video inside `object` tag

```
<object autoPlay="false" data="default-video.mp4" width="50%" height="240" ></object>
```

Video file in same folder and it will auto play and i want autoplay false

inside `object` content like this

```
<object autoplay="false" data="default-video.mp4" width="50%" height="240">
    <html>
        <head>
            <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
        </head>
        <body>
            <video controls="" autoplay="" name="media">
                <source src="http://localhost/default-video.mp4" type="video/mp4">
            </video>
        </body>
    </html>
</object>
```

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/video#attr-autoPlay

Comment: why down vote any reason so please tell me MR. DV

Answer (score 0):

you have to like this in your `<video>` tag

```
<video name="media" controls>
       <source src="http://localhost/default-video.mp4" type="video/mp4">
</video>
```

Here `controls` is attribute to control the video

Comment: but when `youtube video url` in `src` so it will not play.

Comment: can you use iframe tag for youtube video url

Comment: but i use object for both `local video` or `youtube video`